# Diesel 2 fails to deserialize Uuid

Tags: postgresql, rust, uuid, rust-diesel

I've implemented an endpoint and use diesel to interract with the database.

```
pub async fn get(
        user_uuid: web::Path<uuid::Uuid>,
        data: web::Data<AppState>,
    ) -> Result<impl Responder, actix_web::Error> {
        use crate::schema::users::dsl::*;
        let mut conn = get_conn(&data.pool).await?;
        use uuid::Uuid;
        let user_id = user_uuid.into_inner();


        let result: Result<User, diesel::result::Error> = users.find(user_id).first(&mut conn);
        
    }
```

However, I compiler gives me a weird error:

> the trait bound `(uuid::Uuid, std::string::String, ...), diesel::pg::Pg>` is not satisfied the following other types implement
> trait `diesel::deserialize::FromStaticSqlRow<ST, DB>`

My model seems to be implemented correctly, but i use `uuid::Uuid` as an id for my user model. What could be the issue?

```
diesel = {version = "2.1.3", features = ["postgres", "chrono", "r2d2", "uuid", "serde_json"]}
uuid = { version = "1.4.1", features = ["serde", "v4"] }
```

Users model:

```
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
#[derive(Debug, Insertable, Queryable, AsChangeset, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct User {
    pub id: uuid::Uuid,
    pub name: String,
    pub email: String,
    pub password: String,
    pub is_admin: bool,
    #[serde(rename = "createdAt")]
    pub created_at: Option<NaiveDateTime>,
    #[serde(rename = "updatedAt")]
    pub updated_at: Option<NaiveDateTime>,
}
```

schema.rs:

```
diesel::table! {
    users (id) {
        id -> Uuid,
        #[max_length = 100]
        name -> Varchar,
        #[max_length = 255]
        email -> Varchar,
        is_admin -> Bool,
        #[max_length = 100]
        password -> Varchar,
        created_at -> Nullable<Timestamptz>,
        updated_at -> Nullable<Timestamptz>,
    }
}
```

cargo check:

```
`server % cargo check              
    Checking server v0.1.0 
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(uuid::Uuid, std::string::String, std::string::String, std::string::String, bool, std::option::Option<NaiveDateTime>, std::option::Option<NaiveDateTime>): FromStaticSqlRow<(diesel::sql_types::Uuid, Text, Text, diesel::sql_types::Bool, Text, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>), Pg>` is not satisfied
    --> src/routes/user.rs:44:85
     |
44   |         let result: Result<User, diesel::result::Error> = users.find(user_id).first(&mut conn);
     |                                                                               ----- ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `FromStaticSqlRow<(diesel::sql_types::Uuid, Text, Text, diesel::sql_types::Bool, Text, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>), Pg>` is not implemented for `(uuid::Uuid, std::string::String, std::string::String, std::string::String, bool, std::option::Option<NaiveDateTime>, std::option::Option<NaiveDateTime>)`
     |                                                                               |
     |                                                                               required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `FromStaticSqlRow<ST, DB>`:
               <(T0,) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST0,), __DB>>
               <(T1, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST0), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST0), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST0), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST0), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST0), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST0), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, ST0), __DB>>`
```

Comment: Please show the full error (from by `cargo check`) as well as your `users` `table!` definition and `User` model.

Comment: @kmdreko updated the original post

Comment: Order matters, `password` and `is_admin` are in different order between the two. Try making them the same first.

Comment: ooohhhh myyyy gooood. It took me 5 hours and I did not notice that... Thanks a lot!